# Error when uploading an image to ImageField via Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, imagefield

Trying to upload a picture via the Django admin panel and I'm getting an error. The model is:

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/media')

class Picture(models.Model):
    picture_path = models.ImageField(upload_to=fs, blank=True)
    hunter_ID = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    bounty_ID = models.ForeignKey('bountyhunt.Bounty',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    winner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    example_pic = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.picture_path
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError at /admin/hunt/picture/add/
__str__ returned non-string (type ImageFieldFile)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/hunt/picture/add/
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__str__ returned non-string (type ImageFieldFile)
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 76
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/michael/Documents/phoboh',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error indicates, the issue id with your `Picture` model's `__str__` method. Instead of returning a string it is returning an `ImageFieldFile` object.

Change it to return a string - e.g.,

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.picture_path)
```

or:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.picture_path.name
```